# how to find out which jar is being loaded for slf4j

Tags: java, log4j, java-web-start, slf4j, logback

I have a really strange problem in a Java webstart application.  I'm using slf4j and logback for my logging framework but when one of my users runs the webstart application he gets a log4j warning message!  I'm *not* including log4j jars in the webstart application.  Where can log4j possibly be coming from and how do I find out?  I cannot import any log4j classes and call their methods because I cannot compile against a jar file I don't have.

Here are some details:

slf4j 1.7.12
logback classic and core 1.1.3

The main class looks something like this:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MyMain {

    static {
        String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        System.out.println("CLASSPATH = " + classpath);
    }

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyMain.class);

    public void static main( String args[] ) {
        // do stuff...
    }

}
```

The output of this program on my user's Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 is (remember it is a webstart program and there is a JNLP file that is launched from a browser):

```
CLASSPATH = /Library/Internet Plugins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/deploy.jar
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (MyMain).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Here is the JNLP file:

```
<jnlp spec="6.0" codebase="http://example.com/mymain">
  <information>
    <title>MyMain</title>
    <vendor>My Business</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://www.example.com"/>
    <description>My Application</description>
    <description kind="short">GUI Tool</description>
    <icon href="resources/your.appicon.gif"/>
    <icon kind="splash" href="resources/your.splashicon.gif"/>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.8+" max-heap-size="1024M"/>
    <jar href="mymain.jar" main="true"/>
    <jar href="tsallperspectives63dep.jar"/>
    <jar href="activation-1.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="antlr-runtime.jar"/>
    <jar href="appframework-1.0.3.jar"/>
    <jar href="asm-all-repackaged-2.1.88.jar"/>
    <jar href="asm-all-repackaged-2.2.0-b21.jar"/>
    <jar href="batik.jar"/>
    <jar href="beansbinding-1.2.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="cglib-2.1.88.jar"/>
    <jar href="cglib-2.2.0-b21.jar"/>
    <jar href="common.jar"/>
    <jar href="commonj.sdo-2.1.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar"/>
    <jar href="commons-codec-1.6.jar"/>
    <jar href="commons-lang3-3.4.jar"/>
    <jar href="commons-logging-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <jar href="derbyclient.jar"/>
    <jar href="dom4j-1.6.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="eclipselink-2.5.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="guava-14.0.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="hk2-api-2.1.88.jar"/>
    <jar href="hk2-api-2.2.0-b21.jar"/>
    <jar href="hk2-locator-2.1.88.jar"/>
    <jar href="hk2-locator-2.2.0-b21.jar"/>
    <jar href="hk2-utils-2.1.88.jar"/>
    <jar href="hk2-utils-2.2.0-b21.jar"/>
    <jar href="httpclient-4.3.5.jar"/>
    <jar href="httpcore-4.3.2.jar"/>
    <jar href="iText.jar"/>
    <jar href="javaee-api-7.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar"/>
    <jar href="javax.inject-1.jar"/>
    <jar href="javax.inject-2.1.88.jar"/>
    <jar href="javax.inject-2.2.0-b21.jar"/>
    <jar href="javax.mail-1.5.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="javax.persistence-2.1.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="jcommon-1.0.17.jar"/>
    <jar href="jersey-client-2.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="jersey-client-2.4.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="jersey-common-2.0.jar"/>
    <jar href="jersey-common-2.4.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="jfreechart-1.0.14.jar"/>
    <jar href="jfreesvg-2.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="jsse.jar"/>
    <jar href="jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar"/>
    <jar href="junit-3.8.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="logback-classic-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <jar href="logback-core-1.1.3.jar"/>
    <jar href="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    <jar href="ojpse.jar"/>
    <jar href="oraclepki.jar"/>
    <jar href="oraclepki103.jar"/>
    <jar href="osdt_cert.jar"/>
    <jar href="osdt_core.jar"/>
    <jar href="osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="poi.jar"/>
    <jar href="serializer.jar"/>
    <jar href="slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar"/>
    <jar href="sso.jar"/>
    <jar href="swing-layout-1.0.4.jar"/>
    <jar href="swing-worker-1.1.jar"/>
    <jar href="xalan.jar"/>
    <jar href="xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="MyMain">
    <argument>-h</argument>
    <argument>example.com</argument>
    <argument>-u</argument>
    <argument>user</argument>
    <argument>-p</argument>
    <argument>pass</argument>
  </application-desc>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
</jnlp>
```

Note, there is a commons-logging jar that is a transitive dependency of some other jar (I'm not sure which).  I don't think this is related.

Now, I also have Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 and I do not get any warning from log4j... I get what I expect for output:

```
CLASSPATH = /Library/Internet Plug-ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/lib/deploy.jar
20:51:43,748 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
20:51:43,750 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
20:51:43,750 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:http://example.com/mymain/mymain.jar!/logback.xml]
```

I know of two other Mac OS X systems that properly run this webstart app and no others that fail like this one user's system.

All systems are running Java 1.8.0 update 45.

The only possible thing I can think of is that my user's system has some other java application that has installed log4j in a location that is loaded on the classpath or by Java webstart and this is loading before my webstart application.  Possibly this jar is in /Library/Java/Extensions or ~/Library/Java/Extensions.

How do I find out where this log4j message is coming from?  As in... which jar file and where is that jar file stored on the filesystem?

Comment: Yes, Extensions could be a problem. Did you check if there is anything in there?

Comment: Not yet, it's hard since I'm in the US and he is in Australia.  But I will check.

Comment: Well, indeed, some other application put `slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar` in `/Library/Java/Extensions`!!  The author of that program should read this article: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2843688/core-java/java-extension-mechanism-loads-all-jars.html#comments

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that the first sign of this problem was an unexplainable `NoSuchMethodError` in the logging system and I was debugging it by putting code in the `static` clause and printing to stdout to bypass the logging system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out what jar or classpath entry has the slf4j bridge/implementation use the following code in your `MyMain`.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory;

public class MyMain {

    static {
        ILoggerFactory lf = binder.getLoggerFactory();
        Class lfc = lf.getClass();
        System.out.println(lfc.getResource(lfc.getSimpleName() + ".class"));
    }

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyMain.class);

    public void static main( String args[] ) {
        // do stuff...
    }

}
```

Comment: what is 'binder'?

Comment: @PeterSmith, I think it should be `ILoggerFactory lf = org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton().getLoggerFactory();`

Comment: It seems like you need an extra dependency to get the `org.slf4j.impl` package.  `slf4j-log4j12` worked for me, although it also caused sl4fj to complain about finding multiple logger implementations.

Comment: Hmmm... yeah, sorry I didn't compile and run this. I extracted it from a running project and made a mistake in the copy. I have since deleted the code as it was just for debugging, so I don't know for sure what it was. :-( I think @markus_ is correct.